# Trouble accessing friends lists on facebook with Spring social

Tags: java, facebook, spring, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to use the spring social facebook plugin. To do so, I'm using the [quickstart-v3](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-social-samples) sample they provide. It works fine, except one point : with my facebook account, I can browse all my friendlists. I added the permission `read_friendlists` in the application management and the application requests the good rights when used for the first time. However, when I log in to another facebook account (as application admin as me), I get nothing. Do you guys know what the problem could be ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem : I didn't used my app permissions but the graph api permissions. That's why it only worked with me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request read_friendlists permission for every account you're connecting to your app.